How to calculate the last 3 month, 6 month...performance from price?
Disclaimer. I am new to polars.
I have a dataframe that is generated with something like this with polars:
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# Créer une plage de dates
date_ranges = pl.date_range(start=datetime(2000, 1, 1), end=datetime(2025, 12, 31), interval="1d", eager=True)

# Générer des données aléatoires
data = {
    "date": ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01'],
    "prix1": [50,55, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    "prix2": [60,65, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110],
    "prix3": [70,75, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120],
    "prix4": [80,85, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130],
    "prix5": [90,95, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140],
}

# Créer le DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame(data)


I would like to get the last 3 month, 6 month and 1 year performance of the prices ie to get a dataframe that look like this:




Prix 1
Prix 2
Prix 3




Perf 3 Month
=100/70-1
=110/80-1
=120/90-1


Perf 6 Month
=100/55-1
=110/65-1
=120/75-1



Or something like that. It doesnot matter if the output is transpose

what exactly is 'performance' of the prices? It would be helpful if you would add a sample input (not random), it doesn't have to be large + sample output

The performance of price for the last M month is: Price(T)/Price(T-M)-1 where Price(T) is the price at T and T is the last date

Could you add a sample <= 10 rows input + sample output? I think it'd be much easier to help you if example is there.

Are your dates always the 1st of the month? Is there always an entry for every month in the data?

You could filter the dates based on your criteria for each offset, then concat the outputs:
from datetime import timedelta

# convert to datetime if needed
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date))

# get the last date
last_date = df['date'].max()
# define the number of days to consider
days = [93, 184] # 3 and 6 months

# compute the performance and concat
pl.concat([df.filter(pl.col('date')>(last_date-timedelta(days=d))).drop('date')
             .pipe(lambda x: x.tail(1)/x.head(1)-1)
             .with_columns(days_offset=d)
           for d in days])

Output:
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ prix1    ┆ prix2    ┆ prix3    ┆ prix4    ┆ prix5    ┆ days_offset │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---         │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ i32         │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│ 0.428571 ┆ 0.375    ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 0.3      ┆ 0.272727 ┆ 93          │
│ 0.818182 ┆ 0.692308 ┆ 0.6      ┆ 0.529412 ┆ 0.473684 ┆ 183         │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘

If you want to use month offsets, you can update the above code to use a Datetime dtype and Expr.dt.offset_by:
from datetime import timedelta

df = df.with_columns(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Datetime))

last_date = df['date'].max()
months = [3, 6]

pl.concat([df.filter(pl.col('date')>=pl.lit(last_date).dt.offset_by(f'-{m}mo'))
             .drop('date')
             .pipe(lambda x: x.tail(1)/x.head(1)-1)
             .with_columns(months_offset=m)
           for m in months])

Output:
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│ prix1    ┆ prix2    ┆ prix3    ┆ prix4    ┆ prix5    ┆ months_offset │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---           │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ i32           │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0.428571 ┆ 0.375    ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 0.3      ┆ 0.272727 ┆ 3             │
│ 0.818182 ┆ 0.692308 ┆ 0.6      ┆ 0.529412 ┆ 0.473684 ┆ 6             │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────────┘



If you know that you have all months in your DataFrame, you can use get() to get row by its position.
To get the last row you can use last().
I'm using concat() here to not repeat the code.
exclude() to select all the columns except date.

pl.concat(
    df.select(
        pl.lit(f"Perf {i} month").alias("Name"),
        pl.exclude('date').last() / pl.exclude('date').get(-i - 1) - 1
    ) for i in [3, 6]
)

┌──────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Name         ┆ prix1    ┆ prix2    ┆ prix3    ┆ prix4    ┆ prix5    │
│ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ Perf 3 month ┆ 0.428571 ┆ 0.375    ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 0.3      ┆ 0.272727 │
│ Perf 6 month ┆ 0.818182 ┆ 0.692308 ┆ 0.6      ┆ 0.529412 ┆ 0.473684 │
└──────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

If you really want to rely on month, you can use dt.offset_by() and filter():
pl.concat(
    df.select(
        pl.col(c).last() /
        pl.col(c).filter(
            pl.col.date == pl.col.date.dt.offset_by(f"-{i}mo").last()
        ) - 1
        for c in df.columns if c != "date"
    ).select(
        pl.lit(f"Perf {i} month").alias("Name"),
        pl.all()
    )
    for i in [3, 6]
)

┌──────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Name         ┆ prix1    ┆ prix2    ┆ prix3    ┆ prix4    ┆ prix5    │
│ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ Perf 3 month ┆ 0.428571 ┆ 0.375    ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 0.3      ┆ 0.272727 │
│ Perf 6 month ┆ 0.818182 ┆ 0.692308 ┆ 0.6      ┆ 0.529412 ┆ 0.473684 │
└──────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘


Relying on the month integer value won't work if you change years and potentially if you have missing dates and multiple years with the same month.

yep, if it has to go across multiple years. I'll adjust the answer, thanks

Yes, you can use dt.offset_by like I did.

Probably oversimplifying things, but it seems like you could search_sorted by the offsetted date and get the corresponding values.

.offset_by() - generate new date offset by period
.search_sorted() - find index of offsetted date
.get() - extract values at index

df = df.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_date())

months = 3, 6, 12

df.select(
   pl.Series([f"Perf {m} Month" for m in months]).alias("label"),
   pl.concat(
      pl.struct(pl.exclude("date").last())
      / 
      pl.struct(pl.exclude("date").get(
         pl.col("date").search_sorted(pl.col("date").last().dt.offset_by(f"-{m}mo")))
      ) - 1
      for m in months
   )
   .alias("prices")
).unnest("prices")

shape: (3, 6)
┌───────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ label         ┆ prix1    ┆ prix2    ┆ prix3    ┆ prix4    ┆ prix5    │
│ ---           ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str           ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ Perf 3 Month  ┆ 0.428571 ┆ 0.375    ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 0.3      ┆ 0.272727 │
│ Perf 6 Month  ┆ 0.818182 ┆ 0.692308 ┆ 0.6      ┆ 0.529412 ┆ 0.473684 │
│ Perf 12 Month ┆ 1.0      ┆ 0.833333 ┆ 0.714286 ┆ 0.625    ┆ 0.555556 │
└───────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘


If your data ever has gaps and you need to rely on a near date rather than exact matches then you'll need a join_asof. Suppose your starting data looks like
df=pl.DataFrame({
    'date':pl.date_range(pl.date(2000,1,1), pl.date(2025,12,31), '1d',eager=True),
    **{f"prix{i}": np.random.normal(20,1,9497) for i in range(1,6)},
    'rand':np.random.normal(0,1,9497)
}).filter(pl.col('rand')<.85).drop('rand')

Then you can get the summary with
summary=pl.concat([
    df.lazy()
    .slice(-1,1) # remove this slice if you want a summary over time
    .join_asof(
        df.lazy().select(
            pl.col('date').dt.offset_by(f'{i}mo'), 
            pl.col(r'^prix\d+?$').name.suffix('old')),
        on='date'
    ).select(
        pl.lit(f"Perf {i} Month").alias(''),
        # 'date', uncomment this line if you want summary over time
        *[pl.col(prix)/pl.col(f"{prix}old")-1 for prix in df.columns if prix!='date']
    )
    for i in [3,6,12]
]).filter(pl.col('prix1').is_not_null()).lazy()

Making it lazy isn't strictly required but you'll get better performance between optimizations and parallelization.
